# Как динамически выводить данные из базы SQLite в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, sqlite, динамические-массивы, вывод, данные

Здравствуйте делаю рейтинг игроков, у меня есть таблица в юнити  и таблица с информацией о игроках в sqlite, подскажите пожалуйста можно ли сделать так чтобы когда считывалось с базы, автоматически создавались строчки в таблице сколько записей в базе данных и если можно, то можете пожалуйста показать пример?